# Providing common bar legend and color scaling over multiple 3D plots

Tags: plotting, color, legending

#### Data for plot

```
mat11 ={{1.247`,1.2508`,1.26`,1.2769`},{1.1497`,1.1518`,1.1584`,1.1704`},{0.914`,0.915`,0.917`,0.92`},{0.789`,0.789`,0.79`,0.791`}}
mat12={{1.7227`,1.7352`,1.7792`,1.8996`},{1.4969`,1.502`,1.5181`,1.5485`},{1.0731`,1.0737`,1.0755`,1.0785`},{0.908`,0.909`,0.909`,0.911`}}
mat13 ={{1.8568`,1.8731`,1.9332`,2.1544`},{1.5623`,1.5671`,1.5818`,1.6082`},{1.0954`,1.0958`,1.0973`,1.0997`},{0.925`,0.925`,0.926`,0.927`}}
mat14 ={{1.875`,1.8919`,1.9543`,2.1989`},{1.57`,1.5746`,1.5889`,1.6145`},{1.0979`,1.0984`,1.0998`,1.1021`},{0.927`,0.927`,0.928`,0.929`}}
```

#### Plotting code

```
Table[
  ListPlot3D[MATRIX,
    Mesh -> Automatic,
    MeshStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0], Dotted],
    PlotLabel -> 
      Style[
        Framed["Spring const. ratios: Subscript[k, 1] = ??, Subscript[k, 2] = ??"],
        32, Black, Background -> None],
    InterpolationOrder -> 3,
    PlotRange -> {{1, 4}, {1, 4}, {0.75, 2.25}},
    ImageSize -> Large,
    AxesLabel ->
      {Style[μ ,42, Italic, Bold, Red, FontFamily -> "Times"],
       Style[η, 42, Italic, Bold, Blue, FontFamily -> "Times"]}, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Medium, Black, FontFamily -> "Times"],
    PlotLegends-> 
      Placed[
        BarLegend[
          Automatic,
          Round[Range[Min @ mat11, Max @ mat14,(Max @ mat14 -Min @ mat11)/5], 0.01],
          LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 26, Bold]],
        Below],
    ViewPoint -> {-3, -2.9, 2},
    FaceGrids -> {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}},
    FaceGridsStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Dashed],
    ColorFunction -> "CMYKColors",
    Ticks -> 
      {{{1,"0"}, {2,"0.2"}, {3,"0.4"}, {4,"0.6"}}, {{1,"0"}, {2,"0.1"}, 
        {3,"0.5"}, {4,"1"}},
       {0.75,1,1.25,1.5,1.75,2,2.25}}, 
    TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 26]],
  {MATRIX, {mat11, mat12, mat13, mat14}}]
```

How can I make sure that I have the the same range for the barlegend for all four plot ranges in the z-axis (`0.75 < z < 2.25`)? At the moment, the barlegend range only applies to a particular lists; e.g., `mat11` or `mat12`.  I want to have a universal legend such that the range and colour scaling are the same for all four plots.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will give the plot and bar legend coloring you are looking for.

The major medications are

- using `Legended` to place the common bar chart
- revision of the `ColorFunction` option
- adding `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`
- removing the `LabelStyle` option (can't use this option if you style labels in the `AxesLabel` option.

```
minmax = Round[MinMax @ {mat11, mat12, mat13, mat14}, .01];

Column[
  Table[
    Legended[
      ListPlot3D[MATRIX,
        ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"CMYKColors", minmax}],
        ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
        Mesh -> Automatic,
        MeshStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0], Dotted],
        PlotLabel ->
          Framed[
            Style[
              Row[
               {"Spring const. ratios: " , 
                Subscript[k, 1], 
                "= ??, ", 
                Subscript[k, 2] , 
                " = ??"}],
              "TR", Black, Background -> None]],
        InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
        PlotRange -> {{1, 4}, {1, 4}, {0.75, 2.25}},
        ImageSize -> Medium,
        AxesLabel -> 
          {Style[μ, 12, "TBI", Red], Style[η, 12, "TBI", Blue]},
        ViewPoint -> {-3, -2.9, 2},
        FaceGrids -> {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}},
        FaceGridsStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Dashed], 
        Ticks -> 
          {{{1, "0"}, {2, "0.2"}, {3, "0.4"}, {4, "0.6"}}, {{1, "0"}, {2, "0.1"}, 
            {3, "0.5"}, {4, "1"}}, 
           {0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 2.25}}, 
        TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold]],
      Placed[
        BarLegend[{"CMYKColors", minmax},
          LegendLayout -> "Row",
          LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 10, Bold]],
        Below]],
    {MATRIX, {mat11, mat12, mat13, mat14}}]]
```

[image: column]

Note: I have made some cosmetic changes so that the results would look good when posted on this site.